# A Very Elementary Article or Webpage about Secret Sharing

Tags: reference-request, education, cryptography, latin-square

I'm looking for an article or webpage about secret sharing with Latin squares, **accessible to middle school students.** I searched but found none. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you find

[Improved Latin Square based Secret Sharing Scheme](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3991)

and

[Secret Sharing Schemes Arising From Latin Squares](http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/WEBPDF/1994_12.pdf)

not elementary enough, but some technical jargon is inevitable.